# How to keep text on a graph when saving new pine code

Tags: pine-script

I would like to keep the text on a graph when saving new pine coding for that graph. When saving the new pine code, the text is always wiped out. How do i stop this from occurring?

[graph with (text in blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJNCN.png)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an ideal way to do it. When you modify/save the indicator's code, it is reinitializing the sub panel in the same way as if you just added a completely new indicator. Chart objects such as text and lines etc are attached to that previous "indicator" that no longer exists.

There is one "trick". Create a blank indicator that has the same scale as your script. Place this on the chart first. Then add your script and move it to the existing pane of the blank indicator. Now when you draw/text on that pane the chart objects will be part of the blank indicator. When your actual script is modified and reinitialized the chart objects should persist as part of the blank indicator and not the script indicator.